# Prove $\text{sup}\{x\}^{a}=\text{sup}\{x^{a}\}$ for $a\in\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, exponentiation

Assume $X=\{x:x\in\mathbb{Q}\text{ and }x\le t\}$. Here is the proof I've tried for $a\ge 0$:

> If $a\gt 0$, then $x^{a}\le t^{a}$. Hence, $t^{a}$ is an upper bound of $\{x^{a} :x\in X\}$. Suppose there is another upper bound $c$ such that $x^{a}\le c\lt t^{a}$. It contradicts the assumption that $t$ is a supremum of $X$, because it follows $x\le c^{\frac{1}{a}}\lt t$.

However, in an attempt to prove for $a<0$, I've got stuck from the beginning **because $x^{a}\ge t^{a}$ provides no information of $\text{sup}\{x^{a}:x\in X\}$ in the first place**. Then, how can I proceed the proof?

---

**EDIT** :

- I'm yet to learn the concept of continuity (I'm on the 3rd chapter of Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analaysis) . Can you confine yourself to this?
- **If the claim is false for a rational $\color{red}{a<0}$ (as PhoemueX suggests in his comment)** , [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363864/rudin-assumes-xab-xabfor-real-a-and-b-without-proof/1363887#1363887) does not hold (which requires the claim to be true) ?

Comment: Have you tried the general case of a continuous function: f sup{x}= sup {f(x)}

Comment: Hint: For $a <0$, the claim is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot work as you have stated it. The difference between your problem and Rudin's definition is present, yet subtle. First to disprove your statement for $a<0$. Consider the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$. Let $a = -2$. Then your left hand side is going to be $\sup\{1,2,3,4\}^{-2} = 4^{-2} = \frac{1}{16}$. Your right hand side however is $\sup\{1^{-2}, 2^{-2}, 3^{-2}, 4^{-2}\} = \sup\{1,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{9},\frac{1}{16}\} =1$. They are clearly not equal.

Let us now recall Rudin's definition,

Let $b,x\in\mathbb{R}, b > 0,$. Let $B(b,x) = \{b^t\mid t\le x\}$. Then $b^x = \sup B(x)$. Note here the supremum is taken by varying the exponents themselves.

Your question is concerning the supremum over the bases which is a different concept. It is in fact true that if $x > 0$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}$, $$(x^{a})^b = \sup\{B(x,a)\}^b = \sup \{x^t\mid t\le a\}^b = \sup\{\sup\{x^t\mid t\le a\}^s\mid s\le b\} = \sup\{\sup\{x^{ts}\mid t\le a\}\mid s\le b\} = x^{ab}.$$ So then we need to prove that 
$\sup\{x^t\mid t\le a\}^s = \sup\{x^{ts}\mid t\le a\}$. But this is easy. We may assume that $s\in \mathbb{Q}$ and replace all of our previous sets with the added condition that $t,s\in\mathbb{Q}$. So we rewrite $s = \frac{m}{n}$. Then as per an exercise in rudin Ch. 1, $\sup\{x^t\mid t\le a\}^s = \sup\{x^t\mid t\le a\}^{m/n} = \left(\sup\{x^t\mid t\le a\}^m\right)^{1/n} $. We know also the product of supremums is the supremum of a product, provided those supremums exist. So,  $\left(\sup\{x^t\mid t\le a\}^m\right)^{1/n} = \left(\sup\{x^{t(m)}\mid t\le a\}\right)^{1/n} =(x^{am})^{1/n}$. but this again is $x^{a(m/n)}$ (this step may take a second to see). Thus we have gotten to where we need to be. Just keep in mind that the base is fixed and the exponent varies.

Comment: In the second paragraph, $t\in\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: You may take $t,s\in\Bbb{Q}$ throughout this whole answer, I was too lazy to go back and change it, sorry about that.

Comment: Actually, this argument is only true when $x > 0$ the argument will be a little different for negative reals. I suggest you give it a shot to complete the full argument.

Comment: I'll accept (I mean the bounty) your answer in 14 hours. By the way, the proof for $0<b<1$ is done by taking $\frac{1}{b}$, and doing it again?

Comment: No that was because I confused myself by switching the base and the exponent between my proof and definition. The exponent is any real number while the base is positive.

Comment: What did you mean by "the exponent is any real number"? You said above that I need to prove for $x<0$ on my own.

Comment: That was again caused by the switch in notation.  I feel there is a good lesson here.

Comment: I just want to also stress that this whole thing only works when your base is nonnegative. Otherwise you will be taking the sup over complex numbers which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you. It all makes sense now.

Comment: @G.Snapsmath, as you said in your post that this may take time, I really can't crack the third last line: I think $\left(\sup\{x^{t(m)}\mid t\le a\}\right)^{1/n}=\left(\sup\{(x^m)^t\mid t\le a\}\right)^{1/n}=\left((x^m)^a\right)^{\frac 1n}$. How to go from $\left((x^m)^a\right)^{\frac 1n}$ to $\left(x^{\frac mn}\right)^a$?